# How to visualize pages from further down the url?

Tags: php, url-routing

This being the worst title imaginable, let me explain my concern as best as I can. So basically in my framework I use URLs of the type `site.com/controller/method/parameters`

I'll take this page for example `site.com/news/edit/12`

Then, if I apply no routing, my controller's name has to be `News`, the called method will be `edit` with a single parameter `12`. Then if, for the sake of demonstrating my concern, I decide to do editing of the news title and body in different pages, I would have to navigate to `site.com/news/edit/12/title`. Which is where it gets messy and is basically what I want to ask:

What is the proper way of including pages that depend on parameters passed to the controller?

IMHO this looks pretty ugly, and what if I have further more such page separations down the page tree

```
class News {

    public function edit($id, $section){
        if(method_exists($this, $section){
            return $this->$section($id);
        }
    }

    private function title($id){
        // Display page to edit news title
    }

    private function body($id){
        // Display page to edit news body
    }

}
```

Not to mention that this can also cause potential problems with calling existing methods that are not supposed to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't execute methods dynamically based on get params. This can be very dangerous.
One simple way with standard routing:

```
// site.com/news/edit-title/12

public function editTitle($id);
// or depending on your framework
public function edit_title($id);
```

Another perhaps more cleaner solution would be to build your custom routes:

```
// site.com/news/edit/title/12

public function editTitle($id);
```

Comment: @tereško you are right. I updated my answer. I love camelCase because of readability and so I forgot that PHP is for sure case-insensitive about methods.